# Integration by substitution trig

Tags: trigonometry, integration

I need to integrate $\frac {1}{2-\cos x}$ and I am given $t=\tan(x/2)$. What should I do with it?

Comment: What did you try ?

Comment: $\sin x=\frac {2t}{1+t^2}$ and $\cos x=\frac {1-t^2}{1+t^2}$

Comment: Where are you stuck?

Comment: I have $dt/dx=(1/2) \sec^2 (x/2)$

Comment: Can you write $\sec^2{(x/2)}$ in terms of $t$?  If so, then the integral is relatively straightforward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$t=\tan\frac{x}{2}\Longrightarrow x=2\arctan t\Longrightarrow dx=\frac{2}{1+t^2}dt\Longrightarrow$$

$$\int\frac{dx}{2-\cos x}=2\int\frac{dt}{1+t^2}\cdot\frac{1}{2-\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}}=2\int\frac{dt}{1+3t^2}=\ldots$$

And now you're left with a rather easy, almost immediate, integral.

Comment: Shouldn't the second equation be  $x = \arctan 2t$?

Comment: No. It is $$t=\tan\frac{x}{2}\,$$ not $$t=\frac{\tan x}{2}$$

Comment: Ah, my bad. You're right.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Wikipedia article about this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_substitution